# How to initialise Thread to sleep

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, runnable

i am trying to write a method that pings my database every hour. In doing so I am having some difficulties in sleeping the Thread is it might not have been initialised

```
private void pingServer(){
    final Thread serverPing = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Connection conn = null;
            try {
                conn = source.getConnection();
                while(conn.isValid(3600)){
                    //no need to do anything as conn.isValid does the ping
                    serverPing.sleep(3600000);
                }
            } catch (SQLException | InterruptedException e) {}
            finally{
                closeConnection(conn);
            }
        }
    });
    serverPing.setDaemon(true);
    serverPing.start();
}
```

How can i modify this code to initialise it correctly?

Thanks

Comment: `serverPing.setDaemon(true);` --> The JVM will stop if all threads are *daemon* threads. What is the point of setting this thread as a Daemon?, a waiting thread will not even be scheduled by the scheduler, so, there will be minimal hit on efficiency. BTW setting it as daemon also stops `finally` block from executing.

Comment: Thread.sleep() is a static method. It only causes the *current* thread to sleep. "Having some difficulties" is not a problem description.

Comment: no - the bit after is

Comment: "The bit after" being "it might not have been initialized"? Try again. Post a stack trace.

Comment: thanks for your help - i have an answer to me question now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sleep, just use `Thread.sleep(3600000);`

Yet, you should use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) for this kind of tasks:

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try(Connection conn = source.getConnection()){
            if(!conn.isValid(3600)){
                // do something if the connection is invalid
            }
        }
    }
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Comment: if i need the code to run indefinitely - then how do i handle stopping the thread?

Comment: @Biscuit128 scheduleAtFixedRate returns a ScheduledFuture<V> object, which has boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) method.

Comment: @Biscuit128 you can call `ses.shutdown()` to intiate a shutdown of the executor.

Comment: This solution is different from the original:  The original calls source.getConnection() just one time, and then it periodically pings the one connection.  This solution creates a new connection (and does not close it) each time.

Comment: You're right about the creation, but he can easily create the Connection once as ``final`` before creating the ``Runnable``. Yet you are wrong about the closing as I am using the ``try-with-resources`` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just use  `Thread.sleep(TIME_GAP);` to sleep  the current thread.

Example

```
    while(conn.isValid(3600)){
       try {
        Thread.sleep(3600000);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }         
    }
```